spark-shell and pyspark command is not getting initialized after the pre-requisites has been done
I have downloaded the spark tar- spark-3.4.4-bin-hadoop3, hadoop-3 winutils, java jdk - java 23.0.1 and added the environment variables too. Still facing this error.
>>spark-shell
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
ReplGlobal.abort: bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 49842
[init] error:
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 49842
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.12.17
    compiler version: version 2.12.17
  reconstructed args: -classpath  -Yrepl-class-based -Yrepl-outdir C:\TEMP\spark-8c7c7071-0844-45a1-92e7-e97996bb80b8\repl-c344ae8d-0919-4569-97d2-0cc91ad23a37

  last tree to typer: EmptyTree
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: null
           call site: <none> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==


Exception in thread "main" scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 49842
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.12.17
    compiler version: version 2.12.17
  reconstructed args: -classpath  -Yrepl-class-based -Yrepl-outdir C:\TEMP\spark-8c7c7071-0844-45a1-92e7-e97996bb80b8\repl-c344ae8d-0919-4569-97d2-0cc91ad23a37

  last tree to typer: EmptyTree
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: null
           call site: <none> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==


        at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort(Reporting.scala:69)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort$(Reporting.scala:65)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anon$2.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ReplGlobal$$super$abort(IMain.scala:239)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ReplGlobal.abort(ReplGlobal.scala:31)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ReplGlobal.abort$(ReplGlobal.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anon$2.abort(IMain.scala:239)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.errorBadIndex(ClassfileParser.scala:385)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getExternalName(ClassfileParser.scala:249)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.readParamNames$1(ClassfileParser.scala:828)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttribute$1(ClassfileParser.scala:834)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parseAttributes$7(ClassfileParser.scala:908)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttributes(ClassfileParser.scala:908)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseMethod(ClassfileParser.scala:611)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parseClass$4(ClassfileParser.scala:534)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:534)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$2(ClassfileParser.scala:160)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$1(ClassfileParser.scala:146)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:129)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:343)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:250)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1542)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions.scala$reflect$internal$Definitions$$enterNewMethod(Definitions.scala:49)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1134)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus(Definitions.scala:1134)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1438)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods(Definitions.scala:1420)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1450)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1450)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1506)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1214)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain._initialize(IMain.scala:124)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.initializeSynchronous(IMain.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1020)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


it is likely related to a version mismatch or improper configuration between Java, Scala, and Spark.
The primary cause of your issue is likely the usage of Java 17, which is not compatible with Spark 3.4.4. By downgrading to Java 11 and ensuring the correct versions of Scala, Spark, and Hadoop, you should resolve the issue.

From Compatibility Matrix:

Spark 3.4.4: Scala 2.12, Java 8/11, Hadoop 3.x

Spark 3.4.4 officially supported Java version are 8/11/17. Please refer following quotes from Spark 3.4.4 documentation:

Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.7+, and R 3.5+.
Python 3.7 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0. Java 8 prior to
version 8u362 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.4.0. When using the
Scala API, it is necessary for applications to use the same version of
Scala that Spark was compiled for. For example, when using Scala 2.13,
use Spark compiled for 2.13, and compile code/applications for Scala
2.13 as well.

Please refer documentation link at https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/docs/3.4.4/
